# Spring Data JPA - nativequery, param values replace

Tags: spring-data-jpa, load-data-infile, nativequery

Using Spring data JPA, trying to create a generic method to upload csv data to database using `Load Data` mysql. The below code is my attempt. The problem is, the second parameter `tablename` is getting replaced with quotes. Eg: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE Client.csv INTO TABLE 'Client' FIELDS`

Any idea on how to overcome this ??

```
@NoRepositoryBean public interface CustomJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {

@Query(value = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE :filepath INTO TABLE :tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'", nativeQuery = true)
public void bulkInsertUsingCLI(@Param("filepath") String filepath, @Param("tablename") String tablename);

}
```